# Display a <i> in data-content for pop-over

Tags: html

I have a Bootstrap 4 `popover` which is displayed when i `hover-over` my `Font Awesome` icon which i have working but the issue is i need to add a another `Font Awesome` icon inside the `data-content`.

Does this have to be done via `JS` or can it be done directly in the `data-content` attribute

Its driving me mad.

**HTML**

```
<i id="orderDetailsInfoIcon" class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="You can remove items added to your cart by clicking the <i class="far fa-times-circle text-danger"></i>." data-trigger="hover"></i>
```

I have tried escaping it but it dont want to work

```
data-content="You can remove items added to your cart by clicking the <i class=\"far fa-times-circle text-danger\"></i>."
```

And also

data-content="You can remove items added to your cart by clicking the" + '' + "."

And other variants.

I want this

[image]

In this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried InnerHtml? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - I was/am trying without using Javascript/JQuery if it can be helped